# Как сказать <div> чтобы печатал калонку справа от предыдущего, а не снизу?

Tags: php, php7, php5, php7.2

Нужно чтобы 3-ая калонка печаталась рядом со 2-ой, а значение align = "center" печатает в центре снизу. Как быть подскажите?

```
<style type="text/css">
   .block1 { 
    width: 20px; 
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px; 
    border: solid 1px black; 
    float: left;
   }
  </style>

<?php 
$arr = array();

echo '<div class="block1">';
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = rand(1, 100);
    echo $arr[$i].'<br>';
}
echo '</div>';

echo '<div align="justify">' . '<pre>'; // 2-ая калонка
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>' . '</div>';

echo '<div align="justify">' . '<pre>'; // 3-ая калонка
var_export($arr);
echo '</pre>' . '</div>';
```

Comment: Делал со всеми значениями align всё равно делает со следующей строки после 1-го блока

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в стилях дописать для каждого div:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

если правильно понял

```
<style type="text/css">
.block { 
    width: auto; 
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px; 
    border: solid 1px black; 
    float: left;
}

</style>
<? 
$arr = array();

echo '<div class="block">';
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = rand(1, 100);
    echo $arr[$i].'<br>';
}
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="block" align="justify">' . '<pre>'; // 2-ая калонка
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>' . '</div>';

echo '<div class="block" align="justify">' . '<pre>'; // 3-ая калонка
var_export($arr);
echo '</pre>' . '</div>';
```